# ES6 library compiled with laravel-mix not working

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, laravel-mix

I'm building small js es6 library.

```
class Library {
    get(key) {
        console.log("Get")
    }

    set(key, value, options) {
       console.log("Set")
    }


    delete(key) {
        console.log("Delete")
    }
}

export default Library
```

I'm using laravel-mix to compile code.

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix')
mix.js('src/index.js', 'dist')
```

Then I import compiled script in HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <script src="../dist/index.js"></script>
        <script>
            var lib = new Library();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

But I get js error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: Library is not defined`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use ../ in an HTML reference - should be a web path not a file path - I would think that is the problem.